# Differentiation Question: Differentiate the following function. y= $ \frac {(5x^2 + 6 \sqrt x)}{3x}\ $

Tags: calculus

Differentiate the following function.
$$y= \frac {(5x^2 + 6 \sqrt x)}{3x}\ $$

I am stuck when I get to $$\frac{5}{3} + \frac{6}{3}\cdot(-\frac{1}{2})x^{-3/2}$$

How did they get $-\frac{3}{2}$ to become $x\sqrt x$?[image]

Pleased be detailed however, keep in mind that I am only a calculus student. Less math jargon the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^{-\frac 32}=\frac{1}{x^{\frac 32}}=\frac{1}{x^{1+\frac 12}}=\frac{1}{x^1\cdot x^{\frac 12}}=\frac{1}{x\cdot \sqrt x}=\frac{1}{x\sqrt x}.$$

Comment: Why not the 3 root of x?

Comment: @user137452: You mean $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: @user137452: These are the same, i.e. $\frac{1}{x\sqrt x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}}$. But since $x\gt 0$, we have $\sqrt{x^2}=x$. So, we can have $\frac{1}{x\sqrt x}$. I think this is better.